# LibreOffice does not do two-sided printing on HP OfficeJet Pro 7740

Tags: printing, libreoffice, hp

LibreOffice does not do two-sided printing on HP OfficeJet Pro 7740. I loader HPLIP for Linux version 3.16.10 (the last version which fully supports the 7740). The printer is connected by USB cable. On both Ubuntu MATE 17.10 and 18.04, LibreOffice printer setting show 2-sided long-edge duplex printing. The HP Device Manager shows 2-sided long-edge duplex printing. The printer properties at print time show 2-sided long-edge duplex printing. Then LibreOffice prints only 1 side.

By accident, I discovered that Chrome does print 2-sided. This seems to indicate that the problem is in LibreOffice.

Comment: I think this problem is more to LibreOffice related than Ubuntu related.

Answer (score 1):

In Libre Office Click on **File > Printer Settings**

In the pop up dialogue box click **Properties**

On the **Paper tab** check that "**Duplex**" is set to **Long Edge (Standard)**

On the **Device** tab under options in the left column, check that "**Duplexer Installed" = Installed**

**On the **Device** tab check that **"Printer Language Type" = PostScript (Level from driver)**

Click "**Ok**" and the document you are working in should print double sided.

Comment: Dear Burried Alive, I thank you for your answer. I already did all that. It just does not work and I have been unable to contact anyone from the LibreOffice project.

Comment: Wonderful advice. It just does not work. HP OfficeJet Pro 7740 connected with a USB cable. Ubuntu MATE 18.04 18.10 19.04 and 19.10. Program allows setting duplex printing but still does only one-side printing. This bug is more than 5 years old and counting. No one yet assigned to actually fix it.

Comment: Switching the Printer Language Type from PDF to PostScript solved it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also check:

```
Menu -> Administration -> Printer -> *Right Click on you Printer* - >"Installable Options"
```

and fill-in the `CheckBox` for "Duplexer Installed".
This now works for my HP Officejet 8610!

Comment: I don't understand why was my "Answer" Edited? Did I use the textual wrong format?